# Count number of words in many files with unix

Tags: unix

I have a bunch of files named xaa, xab, xac,..., xtf. I need to return the count of words in each of these fies.

I currently have:

```
grep -o ' ' x* | wc -l
```

but this just gives me 1's when there are several words...

(I posted something like this already... I am trying to explain in a clearer manner what I am having trouble with.)

Answer (score 1):

`-l` option of `wc` make it to print line count. To get word count, use `-w` option.

`grep -o ..` prints only the matched parts. Use `cat` instead:

```
cat x* | wc -w
```

**UPDATE** according to the comment:

```
wc -w x*
```

Comment: Yeah, this tells me the total amount of words, but I need to have it divded. Like instead have rows declaring the different amount of words in each file. For example 2 2 2 3 8 9

Comment: @boop, Try `wc -w x*`.

Comment: oh wow! That works! do you know how I can make it only express the first character? meaning the number?

Comment: @boop, `wc -w x* | awk '{print $1}'`

Answer (score 0):

```
cat x* | wc -w
```

should do what you want